# Run Mule as a .NET Microservice

Tags: mule, integration, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

We own a product written in .NET and that uses MS SQL Server. We need to write a new Integration layer that allows integration with a number of third party applications such as Jira, ServiceNow etc. Our endeavor is to use a Microservice based architecture for this integration later and not use an iPaaS or Centralized ESB. Questions are:

1. Can I embed Mule into a .NET Microservice?
2. If no, can I embed Mule into a Java Spring Boot application?
3. In either of the cases above, am I forced to use any other platform/ software from Mulesoft (such as the Mulesoft's Management Plane)?
4. Does Microservce based embedded Mule provide capabilities for performance/ health monitoring etc.?
5. Does Mule support writing any custom code in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the answers below:

1. Can I embed Mule into a .NET Microservice?

No. Mule 4 is a Java application and currently is not meant to be embedded.

2. If no, can I embed Mule into a Java Spring Boot application?

No. Mule 4 is not distributed as an embedded Java library.

3. In either of the cases above, am I forced to use any other platform/ software from Mulesoft (such as the Mulesoft's Management Plane)?

No. You can run Mule as a standalone service or application without using MuleSoft's Control Plane. Be aware that you will lose all management features from the platform.

4. Does Microservce based embedded Mule provide capabilities for performance/ health monitoring etc.?

Please define to what you refer as "Microservice based embedded Mule". If you mean in the scenarios mentioned in questions 1) or 2) then the answer is no, because those are not valid deployment options for Mule 4.

5. Does Mule support writing any custom code in .NET?

Yes. There is a [.Net Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/microsoft-dotnet-connector/3.1/) to execute .Net code from a Mule application. Look for the [last release in the release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/microsoft-dotnet-connector-release-notes-mule-4).